# Best approach to make a background scrolling game?

Tags: android, scroll, game-engine, game-physics, 2d-games

i want to do a 2D game with backgrounds and sprites (views) moving on the screen.

I want to make a game with a scrolling ground. I mean the user must see a horizon in the top part of the screen filling the 30% of the screen size. The ground must be scrolling and must be the 70% of the screen size. For example, if i put a car on the ground, the car must be driving into a scrolling road and the sky (horizon) must be seen on the screen, in the top of the road, filling the 30% of the screen.

I am searching in google about scrolling games but i can't find the way to achieve this kind of scrolling ground game with horizon.

Any ideas and approaches will be grated, i'm just making a research about how to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This kind of effect can be done in various ways, here is one very basic example I can come up with.

First create a background image for your **horizon** - a blue sky with a sun would be good. Now create some **detail** images for the background, such as clouds and birds. These can move accross the background image from left to right (and/or vice-versa). In your rendering code you would render the "background" image first, and then the "detail" images. Make sure that your background image covers around 35% of the screen, so that when you render the 70% ground layer there is some overlap - preventing a hole where the two layers meet.

Next create a textured image for the **ground**. For this I would use a static image that has the correct type of texture for what you are trying to represent (such as dirt). It may also be good to add some basic detail to the top of this image (such as mountains, trees, etc).
This should be rendered *after* the background layer.

Once you have this layout in place, the next step would be to **simulate the depth** of your world. For this you would need to create **objects** (2D images) that would be **placed** in your "world". Some examples would be trees, rocks, houses, etc.

To define your world you would need to store 2 coordinates for each **object** - a position on the **x-axis** as well as a depth value on the **z-axis** (you could also use a y-axis component to include height, but I will omit that for this example).

You will also need to track your player's position on the same x and z axis. These values will change in realtime as the player **moves** into the screen - z will change based on speed, and x will change based on steering (for example).

Also define a **view distance** - the number of units away from the player at which objects will be visible.

Now once you have your world set up this way, the rendering is what will give the illusion of moving into the screen. First render your player object at the **bottom** of the ground layer. Next, **for each** world object, calculate it's distance to the player - if it's distance is within the **view distance** you defined then it should be rendered, otherwise it can be ignored.

Once you find an object that should be rendered, you need to **scale** it based on it's **distance from the player**. The formula for this scaling would be something like:

```
distance_from_player_z = object.z - player.z
scale = ( view_distance - distance_from_player_z ) / view_distance
```

This will result in a float value between 0.0 and 1.0, which can be used to scale your object's size. Using this, the larger the distance from the player, the smaller the object becomes.

Next you need to calculate the position on the x-axis and y-axis to render your object. This can be achieved with the simple 3D projection formulas:

```
distance_from_player_x = object.x - player.x 
x_render = player.x + ( distance_from_player_x / distance_from_player_z )

y_render = ( distance_from_player_z / view_distance ) * ( height_of_background_img );
```

This calculates the distance of the object **relative** to the player on the x-axis only. It then takes this value and "projects" it, based on the distance it is away from the player on the z-axis. The result is that the farther away the object on the z-axis, the closer it is to the player on the x-axis. The y-axis part uses the distance away from the player to place the object "higher" on the background image.

So with all this information, here is a (very basic) example in code (for a single object):

```
// define the render size of background (resolution specific)
public final static float RENDER_SIZE_Y = 720.0f * 0.7f;  // 70% of 720p

// define your view distance (in world units)
public final static float VIEW_DISTANCE = 10.0f;

// calculate the distance between the object and the player (x + z axis)
float distanceX = object.x - player.x;
float distanceZ = object.z - player.z;

// check if object is visible - i.e. within view distance and in front of player
if ( distanceZ > 0 && distanceZ <= VIEW_DISTANCE )  {

   // object is in view, render it
   float scale = ( VIEW_DISTANCE - distanceZ ) / VIEW_DISTANCE;
   float renderSize = ( object.size * scale );

   // calculate the projected x,y values to render at
   float renderX = player.x + ( distanceX / distanceZ );
   float renderY = ( distanceZ / VIEW_DISTANCE ) * RENDER_SIZE_Y;

   // now render the object scaled to "renderSize" at (renderX, renderY)
}
```

Note that if distance is smaller than or equal to zero, it means that the object is **behind** the player, and also not visible. This is important as distanceZ==0 will cause an error, so be sure to exclude it. You may also need to tweak the renderX value, depending on resolution, but I will leave that up to you.

While this is not at all a complete implementation, it should get you going in the right direction.

I hope this makes sense to you, and if not, feel free to ask :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use libgdx (http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/).
The superjumper example will put you in the right way :) (https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/tree/master/demos/superjumper)

Comment: i tryed that way, bit it is not a good way. The android demo requires 3 projects that requires four projects more that each one requires a lot of more projects.... the code is spread into docens of projects.  I want to achieve this by a simple way and only with the code i need to do the scrolling with horizon

Comment: Thats not true xD you can use only two projects if you want (core and android), and the android project is automatically generated, so you actually only use one :) And this library greatly simplifies everything.
But if you still want to use other approach I which you luck! n.n

Comment: lestat i import the android project and the android project gives me 5 errors, two of them are dependences from other two projects. I import the other two projects and they give me a lot of errors more, some of them more dependence projects. I import these new dependence projects and i still get more dependences. Some of them can't be found in the zip, like one of the jars. It is an absolute chaos.

Comment: oh ok, do this: download http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/dist/gdx-setup-ui.jar
Run it with "java -jar".
Fill the fields in the left, choose download nightly build in the middle, and only check Android and core projects in the right.
Generate with the button in the right (when nightly build is downloaded), and then launch.
Then import those 2 generated projects in your workspace. Now, only copy superjumper code and assets to the folders.